# How to get ID between two table?

Tags: mysql

In MySql database have `AM_COURSE`

```
UserId      CourseName   course_desc
  101          java        sometext...
  102          mysql       sometext....
   :
```

`AM_TIMETABLE` table in that

```
UserId        Date_Time
 101        2012-08-08 04:00:00 
 102        2012-08-15 10:00:00
 103        2012-08-18 09:00:00
 104        2012-08-24 05:00:00
```

My Question is, i'm passing start-date and end-date and `CourseName` then i want to get UserId in that way i wrote query

```
select UserId,CourseName,course_desc from AM_COURSE where name='java' and UserId=(SELECT UserId FROM AM_TIMETABLE WHERE `Date_Time` BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00')
```

then i will get 101 UserId value.
but i'm getting error because inner query give two id's...  `please help`

Comment: I don't get it. You want to select the user id by searching for a user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your inner query is returning more than 1 result (and this is valid of course for your scenario) then shouldn't you be using the **IN** clause?

```
select UserId
,CourseName
,course_desc 
from AM_COURSE 
where name='java' and UserId in (
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM AM_TIMETABLE 
    WHERE `Date_Time` BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to rename the ID in each of your tables, perhaps COURSE_ID and TIMETABLE_ID. In this case, you would also create a table containing all User info such as name, email etc.

Once you have the tables set up correctly, Primary Key/Foreign Key pairings would help with connecting between tables and outputting data into conceivable formats.

Answer (score 0):

you can `join` the two tables:

```
SELECT  a.UserID
FROM    AM_COURSE a
            INNER JOIN AM_TIMETABLE b
                ON a.UserID = b.USerID
WHERE   a.CourseName = 'java' AND
        b.Date_Time BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.UserId
FROM   AM_COURSE c
  JOIN AM_TIMETABLE t 
    ON c.UserId = t.UserId
WHERE c.name = 'java'
  AND t.Date_Time BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
select c.UserId,CourseName,course_desc from AM_COURSE c where name='java' and c.UserId=(SELECT t.UserId FROM AM_TIMETABLE t WHERE `Date_Time` BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00')
```